# Angularjs - ng-repeat and nested scope

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angularjs and trying to grasp the concept of accessing data in a nested scope.
Here is the main scope "company" containing a nested scope of objects "contacts":

```
$scope.company = 
      {
        companyName: "",
        contacts: {
          name: "",
          email: ""
        }
      }
```

I'm trying to generate a table with the data from "contacts" scope in each row.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="contact in company.contacts">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.name"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.email"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

But it seems that I'm doing something wrong here, as when I try to display the data from the main scope {{company}} nothing really happens.

I could really use some advice. Thank you.

Comment: In your example contacts is an object, not an array. A loop is used for going through Arrays/Lists

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. How can I access an object with ng-repeat?

Comment: See answer, I couldn't make it into a comment while retaining decent formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use a loop for this. 
Just use `company.contacts.name` and `company.contacts.email`.

However I suspect you might want to have multiple contacts, hence the plural contacts. For that you need to make contacts an array.
With an array you can use the repeat.

Like this:

```
$scope.company = 
      {
        companyName: "",
        contacts: [
         {
          name: "",
          email: ""
         },
         {
          name: "",
          email: ""
         }
        ]
      }
```

Off topic: If you're just learning Angular1 and don't already have a massive project you're working on, switch to Angular2+ (currently 6). AngularJs (1.x) is a framework that's just on long term support for another year and a half. (AngularJs (1.x) and Angular (>= 2 ) are different frameworks.)

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification. Making contacts an array works perfectly! May I ask one more question just to make sure I am on the right track? Is it a correct way to access the last item in the array contacts: var last = $scope.company[$scope.company.contacts.length - 1];
As for the offtop - this is a part of my internship task, so I have no choice but to work with angularjs :) so thank you for helping me out.

Comment: `length - 1` is fine, tho you can also use `$scope.company.contacts.last()`. No problem, don't forget to mark it as solved ;) (accepted answer or something)

Comment: thank you once again, your comment was of a really great help. I will see how I can mark the question as solved :)